# Hibernate tools perspective does not appear after installation on eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-tools, eclipse-neon

I was able to install hibernate tools on eclipse neon Java IDE Standard. At first it failed, afterwards I did an offline installation for GIT, and successfully installed the JBoss Hibernate tools. Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Hibernate tools reported as installed:

[image]

But the perspective is no where to find:

[image]